# prime number and order problem

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Does anyone can solve problem stated at

[Is $n = k \cdot p^2 + 1$ necessarily prime if $2^k \not\equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ and $2^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150853/is-n-k-cdot-p2-1-necessarily-prime-if-2k-not-equiv-1-pmodn-and-2)

?

It should have the additional constraint, k < p.

Comment: Is $p$ a prime number ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $o$ be the order of $n$ to base $2$.

In other words, $o$ is the smallest positive natural number with $2^o\equiv 1\ \ (\ mod\ n\ )$

Because of $2^{n-1}\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ n\ )$, $o$ must be a divisor of
$n-1=kp^2$.

$o$ cannot be a divisor of $k$, because then we would have $2^k\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ n\ )$

So, $o$ must be a multiple of $p$. So, if $n$ is not prime, it must have
the form $(ap+1)(bp+1)=abp^2+(a+b)p+1=kp^2+1$ , with $a,b>0$

It follows $abp+a+b=kp$

Because of $k<p$, we have $ab<p$. Furthermore, we have $a+b\equiv 0\ (\ mod\ p\ )$.If we assume $a<b$, the only way to fulfill these equations is $a=1,b=p-1$.

So, $n=(p+1)((p-1)p+1)=p^3+1$

Which contradicts $n=kp^2+1$ with $k<p$.

So, $n$ must indeed be prime.